# Reversing the search for a convex hull

Tags: finite-groups, locally-convex-spaces

In the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) on convex hulls, there is an image showing a rubber band shrinking down to form a polygon around a set of points in a plane.

I have a set of data with a region with no points and I want to be able to expand outward to create a polygon that encloses the empty region. The empty region will have points but I need to be able to select because their value needs to be set to zero.

Are there algorithms or methods to do this?

Comment: How is the empty region defined?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have data points scattered in 3d. They roughly form a cube. However there is a cylinder shape which embedded in the cube, which runs parallel to the z-axis and this area is without points.